# Vue.JS Table Row CSS Change with Data

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am hoping this is a question that is not answered already, I have looked through the answers and none of them seem to get to the root of my issue, or, I do not have a solid enough grasp on Vue.JS to understand how they can be applied to my situation.

I am using Vue.JS to create a table and filling it with data from a web source. The table can populate just fine, and it works well.

However, I am trying to figure out how I can make each of the rows that are populated with the information a certain color dependent on the value of the data. For example, if the value of the data is between, say, 0 and 12, I want the row to highlight green. If it is between 12 and 30, highlight red, etc.

I have looked extensively into v-bind, and I am pretty confident this is the way to do it. I am familiar with how v-bind basically works, and I can do fairly simple things with it no problem. I just cannot wrap my head around how to combine v-bind with this data and make it function. I hope this is detailed enough.

If more info is needed, please ask.

Thank you!

[Here is the table in my html.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN70q.png)
[This is just the outline of my vue instance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn6ZO.png)
[These are the classes of what the rows could, depending on the data, be colored.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY3mR.png)

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about v-binding and you want to bind to a class using the data value to determine the class. I got this to do what you want.

```
<template>
  <table v-for="(stuff, i) in stuffs" :key="i">
      <tr :class="getClass(`${stuff.a}`)">
        <td>{{stuff.a}}</td>
        <td>{{stuff.b}}</td>
        <td>{{stuff.c}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
          stuffs: [
            {a: 17, b: 'blaa', c: 'hmmm'},
            {a: 6, b: 'blah', c: 'hmmm'},
            {a: 112, b: 'blah', c: 'hmmm'},
            {a: 4, b: 'blah', c: 'hmmm'},
            {a: 45, b: 'blah', c: 'hmmm'}
          ], 
          class: ''
        }),
        methods: {
          getClass(a) {
              if (a<10) {
                this.class="first"
                return this.class
              }
              if (a>11 && a< 100) {
                this.class = "second"
                return this.class
              }
              else {
                this.class = "third"
                return this.class
              }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
    .first{
      background-color: blue
    }
    .second {
       background-color: red
    }
    .third {
       background-color: green
    }
</style>
```

Obviously a pretty basic example but you should be able to get it to do what you want.

Comment: Does data binding work with methods within the new Vue? i.e. if I needed to do a bunch of if statements within the Vue I am using to bind the class, does that work?

Comment: Yes, it does. That is what my answer is showing. Using `:class` is just short hand for writing `v-bind:class` and as you can see, it is calling a method. So then you can have any number of if statements in your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using v-if

```
 <td class="tdlabel" v-if="customerID>=10" style="background: red">ID</td>
 <td class="tdlabel" v-if="customerID<0" style="background: green">ID</td>
      // more v-else-if
 <td class="tdlabel" v-else style="background: you color">ID</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```css
    .danger{
     background-color: #696969;
    }
    .success{
    background-color: #000000;
    }
```

```html
    <tr v-bind:class="{danger:ValueOfTheData< 12,danger:ValueOfTheData < 30}">
      <td>RowData</td>
    </tr>
```